# How to create a rectangle that exactly fills the device screen

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create a Rectangle that fills the device's screen. I've tried this:

```
Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame( height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
            .frame( width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Using this extension:

```
extension UIScreen{
   static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
   static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
   static let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
}
```

However, the height is slightly too small: 
[image]

and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

If you are filling the screen why not just set the `Color` of the `View`?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.green
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

---

And you can stack other `Views` on top of that using a `ZStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            // Other Views on top here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just as below

```
Rectangle()
   .fill(Color.green)
   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```